# Li с float left, как отобразить правильно?

Tags: html, css, список

http://jsfiddle.net/RC8vX/

Необходимо, чтобы строка была высотой с блок максимальной высоты в этой строке

Comment: Может лучше таблицы применить? Вроде как раз тот случай, когда они идеально подходят?

Answer (score 1):

Без танцев с бубном врядли получится. Попробуйте как нибудь так http://jsfiddle.net/RC8vX/4/ Правда надо "потанцевать" с границами еще :))

Comment: это был бы хороший вариант, который я тоже рассматривал, но есть одно "но" - тянущийся сайт ) т.е. количество элементов в строке не фиксировано...